# grep Regex to find in specific words in a file

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I have a file with contents like:

```
this is text file, \"value\":\"ABCD1000\" , this file contains some weird text, \"value\":\"ABDFD1000\" ...
```

I want extract all the values like 'value :ABDC1000'

```
I am using grep command as: grep -o '"value\\":\\\"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\\"' file.name
```

But it does not gives any output.

What am I doing wrong here.

I used http://regexr.com/ to check my regex and it looks correct.

Comment: What output are you trying to get? There may be better tools.

Comment: Capture `value` and `ABCD1000` as two groups and then substitute.

Comment: You use too many backslashes (only two for a literal backslash), and the + quantifier doesn't exist in BRE (Basic Regular Expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -o '\\"value\\":\\"[^\\]*\\"' file | tr -d '\\"'
```

Output:

```
value:ABCD1000
value:ABDFD1000
```

Comment: Is there a way by which I can extract just the actual values, like




    ABCD1000
    ABDFD1000

Comment: With GNU grep: `grep -Po '\\"value\\":\\"\K[^\\]*(?=\\")' file`

Comment: Which version of grep do you use? I use GNU grep 2.6.3.

Comment: I am not sure. I am new to linux and not sure how to check that.

Comment: Try `grep --version`. This worked too: `echo 'this is text file, \"value\":\"ABCD1000\" , this file contains some weird text, \"value\":\"ABDFD1000\" ...' | grep -Po '\\"value\\":\\"\K[^\\]*(?=\\")'`

Comment: I am using grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1
Tried that but still no output. I was able to get the result from



     grep -o '\\"value\\":\\"[^\\]*\\"' file | tr -d '\\"'